# Combination of all Array elements in an incremental order starting from first index to store in a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to print all String array elements from the starting index in an incremental order on each separate line.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = {"a","b","c","d"};
        int j=0;

        for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
           while(j<=i){
              if(j==0)
                System.out.print(str[j]);
              else
                System.out.print(" > "+str[j]);
           j++;
           }
        }
        System.out.println();
        j=0;                    //resetting j to zero index
    }
}
```

My Output is fine as expected where each array element is appended by ">" symbol in an incremental order : -

```
    a
    a > b
    a > b > c
    a > b > c > d
```

My Question is: -

How to store each output line in a separate string for further processing.

As per logic, it only appends ">b" or ">c" or ">d" on output stream but I need to store each output sentence in a string. Please help me with this. I dont underatand, can we achieve this using System.out stream.

I am new in Java. Thank you

Expected output: - I want to read each output in a String, like

```
    String sentence = "a";
```

Next time, sentence will be

```
    String sentence = "a > b";
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you wan to achieve?

Comment: how does this even work ? You increment `j` outside of the while loop. This would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Juan. I want to store each output sentence as per given in a separate String. I dont know more about System.out stream. Can we store them a String?

Comment: Use a StringBuilder at each iteration of the outer loop, append to the StringBuilder instead of writing to the output. At the end, transform the StringBuilder to a STring, add the string to a list, and print it.

Comment: You should first fix your code, which doesn't work at all right now, as Chandler correctly pointed out.

Comment: Ok thank you JB Nizet

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = {"a","b","c","d"};
        int j=0;
            StringBuilder store = null;

        for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){

           while (j < str.length){
              if(j==0)
                      store = new StringBuilder(str[j]);
              else
                store = new StringBuilder(store + " > "+str[j]);
                  String value = store.toString();
                   System.out.println(value);
                   j++;
           }
        }

        System.out.println();
        j=0;                    //resetting j to zero index
}
```

Comment: @ Malik Abdullah Thank you